# Matplotlib opens two graphs...I only want one

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So I am making a plotting script. I am going to be using text files with a lot of data...like on the order of ten thousand coordinates. So I want to initialize an object that creates a plot and then I can show the plot multiple times without having to reload all the data again and again.

I am making two types of graphs...position (x, y, z) and energy vs time (t, KE).

Everything works in my code, but when I call on the class to plot JUST one of the graphs (i.e. position or energy, but NOT both), it shows both.

Any ideas?

Code is below:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def make_plot(x, y, z, title):
    '''
    returns a plt object that can be saved to show later
    x, y, z are lists of floats, but the 0th index is a string: the title of that axes.
    title is a string
    '''
    fig = plt.figure()
    #If there is no z list, the graph should only be 2d (energy vs time)
    if z != None:
        plot = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
        plot.set_zlabel(z[0])
        plot.plot(x[1:], y[1:], z[1:], c='r', marker='o')
        plot.set_xlabel(x[0])
        plot.set_ylabel(y[0])
        plot.set_zlabel(z[0])
    else:
        plt.plot(x[1:], y[1:], c='r', marker='o')
        plt.xlabel(x[0])
        plt.ylabel(y[0])
    plt.title(title)
    return plt  

class Plot(object):
    '''
    Makes every plot its own object.
    '''
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, title):
        self.p = make_plot(x, y, z, title)
    def show_plot(self):
        self.p.show()

class Graph(object):
    '''
    Reads from a file that has 5 columns: x, y, z, t, KE
    There are two graphs I want to make; a position graph (x, y, z)
    and a Kinetic energy vs Time graph (t, KE)
    '''
    def __init__(self, filename, xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', zlabel='Z', tlabel='t', elabel='KE', title='Title'):
        self.title = title
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        data = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        #first index of the lists are what I am going to name the axes
        self.xList, self.yList, self.zList, self.tList, self.eList = [xlabel], [ylabel], [zlabel], [tlabel], [elabel]
        lines = []
        for element in data:
            lines.append(element.split())
        for element in lines:
            #In case I decide later to add comments in my file with the points
            #I added this try statement so it won't add a comment to my point lists
            try:
                self.xList.append(float(element[0]))
                self.yList.append(float(element[1]))
                self.zList.append(float(element[2]))
                self.tList.append(float(element[3]))
                self.eList.append(float(element[4]))
            except:
                pass
        #I want to make a position plot and an energy plot that is loaded
        #and ready to show whenever.
        self.position = Plot(self.xList, self.yList, self.zList, self.title)
        self.energy = Plot(self.tList, self.eList, None, self.title)
    def plot_position(self):
        self.position.show_plot()
    def plot_energy(self):
        self.energy.show_plot()

a = Graph(filename='table.txt')
a.plot_position()
#I only want it to graph the position graph here, but it graphs the position and energy graphs.
```

Comment: In your make_plot method you are returning the 'plt' module, is that intentional?

Comment: Yes. This way I have a plt object with everything loaded. So I can assign a variable to make_plot() and later say variable.show() and it plots with no delay because everything is already loaded. This way works because my plots open up. Unfortunately, more than one plot opens.

Comment: `a.plot_position()` ends up calling `plt.show()`. Since you already have created two figures, both of them are shown. What else did you expect?

Comment: That is because you make it load a graph for position and for energy. When finally running `plt.show()` it shows all graphs in memory, in this case two.

Comment: Does it actually take a long time to generate the graphs once the data is loaded? Your script seems very convoluted, it would be better if you make a call to `make_plot` for position and energy seperatly.

Comment: `plt` is a module that manages the global state.  You should be using the OO interface and returning `Axes` and `Figure` objects.